# Using the apt list command to output to a file (Debian)

Tags: linux, command, debian, pipe, apt

I want to take the entire list that generates from the apt list command and save or view it in a file. Either in nano or some form of a text editor. I thought of piping results into a file, any help would be appreciated, Thank You!

Comment: apt list >/tmp/mytextfile.txt  will do the trick

Comment: Didn't work   "WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As updated to specfic sceniro The quick solution is to use

```
apt list | awk '{print $1}' | tee a.txt
```

where `a.txt` is the file name.

The above command simply pipe the output from `awk` to tee command which report to cli as well as write to file

Comment: I don't want to see the upgradables, I want the entire Raw list into a file. The commands did not work on debian, not sure which distribution you were using.

Comment: apt list | awk '{print $1}'  ------- worked and gave me 1st word but couldnt redirect into a .txt file

Comment: Thank You it Worked? @Sudip Ghimire

Comment: If it did help accept the answer and also dont forget to upvote :)